# template blocks start or end with "{%-" or "-%}" symbols

Tags: templates, flask, block, jinja2

I'm reading ["flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html"](https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/blob/master/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html) on GitHub, and find some block symbols strange, like `{%- block ... %}` or `{% endblock ... -%}`. Why there is "-" before or after `{%` or `%}`?

Will it make the block declaration different than the normal? I'm going to extend this file, so I'd like to know in detail.

Comment: They're used to [control whitespace](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#whitespace-control).

Comment: Thanks, dirn! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular feature (whitespace control) is not from the Flask server, but from [Jinja2 template engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#whitespace-control).

From the linked docs:

> You can also strip whitespace in templates by hand. If you add a minus
>   sign (`-`) to the start or end of a block (e.g. a **For** tag), a
>   comment, or a variable expression, the whitespaces before or after
>   that block will be removed:
>
> ```
> {% for item in seq -%}
>     {{ item }}
> {%- endfor %}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the doc link, hjpotter92! I didn't find it by google. Good to know that sign (-) does have a purpose.